# Expanding beyond parent div causing problem on mobile

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have a full width background with my bottom div without changing the page layout structure. The following code allowed me to have a full background color (dark purple) just as I wanted it [here](http://chakraco.club/). But when I checked the page on my phone, I saw that the bottom went up to `9999px`. If I put `overflow: hidden`, then I dont get the full width background. Please help, thank you!!

[image]

```
.nextpage {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #2D0072;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 33px 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.nextpage:before, .nextpage:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2D0072;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 9999px;
}
.nextpage:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.nextpage:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the best way to tackle this would be to arrange your layout HTML...

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="page-width">
      // header stuff here
    </div>
  </header>
  <content>
    <div class="page-width">
      // main content stuff here
    </div>
  </content>
  <footer>
    <div class="page-width">
      // footer stuff here
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Then the CSS...

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
}

.page-width {
  margin: 0 auto; // centers your block element if smaller that it's parent
  max-width: 1200px; // you decide
}
```

But you can't alter your layout?? You will have to do some hackery...

CSS

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

stuff-in-footer {
  margin: 0 auto; // for centering
  max-width: 1200px; // you decide
}
```

The hackery needed is to put a bottom margin on the rest of your page so you can see it when fully scrolled. Also, 'fixed' will position the footer on the bottom of the page, as the CSS is written above, no matter the scroll position of your page. Some JS might be needed to apply the right bottom margin on your content based on the display height of your footer, and more to reveal the footer when the page is fully scrolled.

Comment: Hi Brent, apologies for the confusion, its not the footer I have the problem with, its the `nextpage` block. Thats why I cannot use the footer css hack you're suggesting.

Comment: No worries, I'll leave the answer for structuring the layout for this purpose, but you can easily get what you need by adding ```overflow-x: hidden;``` to the ```<div class="row">``` or ```<div class="panel-panel bottom col-lg-12">```. Whichever you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Check your media queries. Loading the page in a desktop browser and scaling the width of the window down vs loading the page on mobile on BrowserStack generates very different results.